Finding $(x,y,z)$ in System of equations.

Finding $(x,y,z)$ in


$\displaystyle 3x-4y+\frac{1}{xy}=12$


$\displaystyle 4z-12x+\frac{1}{zx}=3$


$\displaystyle 12y-3z+\frac{1}{yz}=4$

What I try : Multiply $(1)$ by $xy$
And $(2)$ by $yz$ and $(3)$ by $zx$
So we have
$3x^2y-4xy^2+1=12xy\cdots (1)$
$\displaystyle 4z^2x-12x^2z+1=3zx\cdots (2)$
$\displaystyle 12y^2z-3yz^2+1=4yz\cdots (3)$
Now  I am trying $(1)-(2)$  and $(2)-(3)$ , But could not get anything Good.
Please have a look on that , Thanks

Are you solving over the reals or the complex numbers?

@Calvin Lin , For real numbers

Let $xyz=1/k$, then we have the "linear" system:
$$3x-4y+kz=12 $$
$$-12x+ky+4z=3$$
$$kx+12y-3z=4$$
Solve to get the real solution: $x=4/k, y = 3/k, z = 12/k$ in terms of $k$.  Then $1/k=xyz=4/k\times3/k\times12/k \implies k=\pm12$ and we are done.

P.S.: When solving the above system, you will need to assume the determinant (of the relevant matrix) is non-zero, or $k(k^2+169)\neq0$, which is where the non-real solutions get lost. Quite obviously we cannot have $k=0$, but $k=\pm13i$ lead you to the other complex solutions.

Hint: Taking the resultant polynomials of $(1),(2)$ and of $(1),(3)$ and then of these two resulting polynomials, I obtain the single polynomial equation, which is
$$
f(z)(z + 1)(z - 1)=0.
$$
with
$$
f(z)=4137120z^6 + 28392z^5 + 8185177z^4 - 56784z^3 + 4331808z^2 + 28392z + 625.
$$
For $z=1$ it follows that $y=\frac{1}{4}$ and $x=\frac{1}{3}$. For $z=-1$ one obtains $y=-\frac{1}{4}$ and $x=-\frac{1}{3}$. The sextic polynomial $f$  has no real roots. So the only real solutions are the ones with $z=\pm 1$. Over the complex numbers we obtain $6$ additional solutions.
